# Laravel: These credentials do not match our records

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image]

I don't know why, I tried to change my admin's password from the Cpanel, the password is changed successfully but this problem occurs when I try to hit the new password. I also tried the old password, it doesn't work. Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Laravel hashes the password, you will need a hashed password in the cPanel for it to work. You are probably using a string you typed yourself.

Comment: Yes exactly! I typed a string to change the password but I don't have enough ideas on how can I fix it.

Comment: I think the safest way would to make a route that will hash your string `Hash::make()` and then echo it. Make sure to include the class `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` You can find more info here on hashing: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing

Comment: I think it will help me a lot, thank you

Comment: Please share more details - are you facing any error? Then add the error in text form to your question. Also, if this is related to Laravel, please share the code involved

Comment: Nico Haase, I don't think this is an error from the code because it is already 3/4 years of running the website. What I did a mistake is I try to change the password from the Cpanel and the "These credentials do not match our records" error occurs. And the problem is I don't have that good knowledge about PHP to fix it myself. Thank you!

Comment: What is "the password" you've changed? How does your own application relate to settings in cPanel?

Comment: "Transformingworld" is the password I've changed through cPanel. My application is related to cPanel because I think it has been 3 to 4 years since being hosted. So I thought it might be good to change my password through cPanel. Now I realize the process might be wrong.??

Comment: You need to share more details on what you've tried, when you say you've "hit the new password" does that mean you've tried the password resetter in your screenshot? Do you receive any errors? Have you checked the console log in Google Chrome?

You may be able to code a password resetter or upgrade to latest laravel and resolve that way.